# Error when concat two arrays in Spark dataframe column

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I m working with dataframe that contains two arrays I want to get from this two arrays one array:

```
   df.show()
   root
     |-- context_id: long (nullable = true)
     |-- data1: array (nullable = true)
     |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |-- k: struct (nullable = false)
     |    |    |    |-- v: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- t: string (nullable = false)
     |    |    |-- resourcename: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- criticity: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- v: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- vn: double (nullable = true)
     |-- data2: array (nullable = true)
     |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |-- k: struct (nullable = false)
     |    |    |    |-- v: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- t: string (nullable = false)
     |    |    |-- resourcename: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- criticity: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- v: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- vn: double (nullable = true)
```

I create `udf` that concat tow arrays and I provided the schema of the result

```scala
val schema=df.select("data1").schema
val concatArray = udf ({ (x: Seq[Row], y: Seq[Row]) => x ++ y}, schema)
```

when I apply my udf I get this error

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$11: (array<struct<k:struct<v:string,t:string>,resourcename:string,criticity:string,v:string,vn:double>>, array<struct<k:struct<v:string,t:string>,resourcename:string,criticity:string,v:string,vn:double>>) => struct<data1:array<struct<k:struct<v:string,t:string>,resourcename:string,criticity:string,v:string,vn:double>>>)
```

any suggestions please

Answer (score 0):

The way you provide schema is incorrect. The schema for a single column `DataFrame`

```
df.select("data1").schema
```

is not the same as the schema for the column itself. Instead you should use schema of the field:

```
val schema = df.schema("data1").dataType
```